# Properly Using Android Listeners

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper, telephonymanager, sqlite

I'm new to Android programming and while I have successfully logged the output of a listener for a state change in the Telephony API, I'm having trouble accessing the value and writing it to a database.  I can write to the log from within the inner class but can't save to DB as I can't access the helper from within the inner class.  I'm also having trouble calling getSignalStrengths() method.  these are all learning exercises and any advice would be much appreciated.

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

String sSstr = "initial value";

public String getSignalStrengths(){
 return sSstr;
}

public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
 super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
 sSstr = signalStrength.toString();
 Log.v("Test", sSstr);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is MyPhoneStateListener an inner class?

Comment: Yes, it is, should have clarified.

Comment: What is the outer class name and is it an activity?

Comment: MainActivity extends Activity, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your database inside the MyPhoneStateListener in a couple of way

1. Create a MyPhoneStateListener constructor with a Context parameter and use this context to  instantiate your database class.
2. Just instantiate your database class using

   ```
   MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(MainActivity.this)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Exactly what I needed to understand.